# Share a folder between computers in Real Time

Tags: windows, sync, file-sharing, sharing

I have a computer connected over a LAN with four other computers
with a shared folder.

I would like to have the same folder on my computer at Home,
synced in Real-time over the Internet.

How can I accomplish this without using any third-party-software?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: i helped him edit this question to reword it, the votes were before that edit. i would suggest that you guys try to stop alienating new users to this website with this put on hold nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows Homegroup**

Assuming the computers are using Windows 7 or Windows 8, a Windows Homegroup is one of the easiest ways to share files between them. Windows home networking has been extremely complicated to configure in the past, but Homegroup is easy to set up. Just create a Homegroup from the Homegroup option within Windows Explorer (File Explorer on Windows 8) and you’ll get a password. Enter that password on nearby computers and they can join your Homegroup. They’ll then have access to your shared files when they’re on the same network — you can select the libraries you want to share while creating a Homegroup.

**Create-homegroup-windows-7**

[image]

Someone using the other PC will just have to select the Homegroup option in their file manager, browse your shared files, and download them to their computer. If a guest comes over, you don’t have to do any complicated Windows networking configuration on their PC — just give them the password to the Homegroup and they can quickly join it.

credit: http://www.howtogeek.com/166407/how-to-easily-share-files-between-nearby-computers/

Comment: He asked for solution for doing it over the Internet, not LAN.

Comment: he also said he has 4 computers on LAN, i think he just doesnt understand what he is asking for.

Comment: It sounds like 5 networked computers at work with a shared folder and he wants his home computer to be able to access that shared folder, also.